# Indicate more than one ID on JSON url

Tags: json, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm developing a JSON WCF Web Service with C#.

I've just defined these two urls:

```
http://localhost:39325/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms

http://localhost:39325/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms/{id}
```

To retrieve to get all forms or a form with an {id}.

But now, I need to another one: I want to get all forms whose IDs are not included on a set. In other words, on client I will have some forms. I need to get new forms only (those which are not yet on client).

How can I specify an ids list on JSON url?

Answer (score 1):

Use a query string to filter the list of all forms. Something lin what's below

```
http://localhost:39325/RestServiceImpl.svc/forms?NotIn=1&NotIn=2&NotIn=3
```